# arquilian test not pickedup by maven

Tags: java, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I am kind of new to arquillian, 
I have written sample arquillian test. which is working from eclipse if I am running run as junit.

Where as if I am running from CLI/maven with appropriate profile. its unable to detect the arquillian test cases.

See the pom file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"` xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Math-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>Math-ejb</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                    <clientIncludes>
                        <clientInclude>**/CalcLocal.*</clientInclude>
                    </clientIncludes>
                    <clientExcludes>
                        <clientExclude>**/Cal.*</clientExclude>
                    </clientExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arq-jboss</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <!-- This optional build configuration downloads and extracts JBoss AS 
                automatically -->
            <!-- Remove it if you want to use an existing installation defined by 
                the JBOSS_HOME environment variable -->
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack</id>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>jboss-as-dist</artifactId>
                                            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                                            <type>zip</type>
                                            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: What is the name of the test? Is it matching the default surefire test names (**/Test*.java, **/*Test.java, **/*TestCase.java)? If not you might need to change the surefire include setting. If the names match, are there other tests (non Arquillian) which do run? How do you know that they are not found? Could there be another problem? Did you build with the '-X' option enabled?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".